# Webbrowser Control stealing shortcuts

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, shortcut

Webbrowser Control in my .NET Windows Form application is stealing shortcuts when on focused. To able to use `Alt + F4` I had to click a control first.

Currently "`WebbrowserShortcuts = false`" but it's still same.

Is there a way to stop this irritating behaviour?

Comment: What is being displayed in the WB?  Anything like an Office document or a .pdf?

Comment: no it's just HTML which I filled up via DocumentText

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when loading Silverlight inside a winforms WebBrowser and I solved it by adding the following to the `<body>` element:

```
onload="document.getElementById('silverlightControl').focus()"
```

...which, of course, meant I have to give an id of `silverlightControl` to my `<object>` element:

```
<object id="silverlightControl" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
```

If you only have HTML, maybe you can call `focus()` on the `document` or perhaps the first hyperlink?

Comment: I ran across this answer becase I was having the same problem, and tried onLoad='document.focus();'. That didn't work (it's just plain HTML in the WebBrowser, with jQuery being used but nothing started). WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false.

When I set that to true, it DOES allow me to exit, BUT I don't want all the other shortcuts enabled either, so I can't do that.